# $\{h\in A^B|h \text{ is invertible}\}$ is equiumerous to $\{k\in B^A|k \text{ is invertible}\}$ and $\aleph_0$ right invertibles for a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> 1.Let $A,B$ be sets, prove: $\{h\in A^B|h \text{ is invertible}\}$ is equinumerous to $\{k\in B^A|k \text{ is invertible}\}$
>
> 2.Let $A,B$ be sets and a function $f\in A^B$ give an example right invertible functions for $f$ such that there are exactly $\aleph_0$ such functions. (No need to prove there are $\aleph_0$ function but just to describe them).

1. Let $h$ be an invertible function $B\to A$ so it's a bijection and so is it's inverse $h^{-1}:A\to B$, since $h^{-1}:A\to B$ then $h^{-1}\in \{k\in B^A|k \text{ is invertible}\}$ so $$\{h\in A^B|h \text{ is invertible}\}\subseteq\{k\in B^A|k \text{ is invertible}\}$$ and the same is done in the other direction.
2. we need to find $\aleph_0$ injections on $f$. Suppose $f\in \mathbb N^{\mathbb Q }$ then the injections would be $g\in \mathbb Q^{\mathbb N }$. I thought about Cantor's diagonal of the rationals, there are $\aleph_0$ ways to do it and since it's an injection on the rationals we're done.

Is this alright? Are there $\aleph_0$ diagnolizations on the rationals?

Comment: regarding 1, the sets are clearly different unless $A=B$ or $|A|\ne |B|$. I assume you mean equiumerous instead of equal. - What does "such" in 2 refer to?

Comment: Yes equinumerous, about 2, the question asks to describe a set of right invertible functions for $f$ such that that set's cardinality is $\aleph_0$, I hope that's more clear... @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: What do you mean by "invertible"? If it means a bijection, then the proof is almost correct; if it just means an injection or surjection (but not necessarily both), then the statement itself is incorrect. Judging by the second part, it means the latter which poses a problem.

Comment: invertible = הפיכה so it's a bijection. right invertible is הפיכה מימין so an injection. @AsafKaragila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, begin by observing that $A^B\cap B^A$ is rarely a non-empty set. So the inclusion there is out of place. You should write $|\ldots|\leq|\ldots|$ instead.

And indeed the map $h\mapsto h^{-1}$ is the intended bijection, but you need to justify why this is a bijection and you only justified why it is well-defined (which is also important). Namely, why different $h_1,h_2$ give two different inverses and why every function is the inverse or some bijection from $B$ To $A$. Those are not difficult arguments, but they need to be made.

For the second part, I assume that the question is asking for a surjection $f\colon B\to A$ such that there are exactly $\aleph_0$ injections $g$ for which $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_A$. I'm not quite sure what you were trying to do there, but given an enumeration of the rational numbers, there are uncountably many ways to permute its indices to create new enumerations, and therefore the idea that there are only countably many ways to enumerate the rationals is fundamentally flawed.

**HINT:** Find a function $g$ which is almost a bijection from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb N$, and there is a unique $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $\{k\in\Bbb Z\mid g(k)=n\}$ is not a singleton, such that there are exactly $\aleph_0$ ways to reverse $g$.

Comment: Showing that $g:h\to h^{-1}$ is a bijection is simply from the definition of $g$ that $g\circ h=h^{-1}$ it's like two lines... Good to know that it should be done.

Comment: for 2. I could find an almost bijection and my intuition tells me something needs to be done with 0 but I'm not sure what: $f(x)=\begin {cases}2x &, x>0 \\ 2(-x)+1 &,x<0  \end{cases}$

Comment: The first comment has no semantical content. Is $g$ a function *between* the sets or a function between the functions, and why does $g\circ h=h^{-1}$? Is $g(h)=g\circ h$? That sounds improbable. For the the second case, instead of writing a bijection from $\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ and $\Bbb N\setminus\{0,1\}$, follow my hint closely. Write a function from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb N$ which maps exactly one integer to each $n>0$, and infinitely many integers to $0$ (you can replace $0$ by some other fixed natural number).

Comment: I see I mixed things up now with 1. $g:h\to h^{-1}$ is from one set to the other. showing 1-1, take $h_1,h_2$ suppose $g(h_1)=g(h_2)$ since there's only one unique inverse for every bijection we have $h_1^{-1}=h_2^{-1}$, showing g is onto, for every bijection $h^{-1}$ exist one inverse $h$. That should be good now (I hope). I'll think more about 2.

Comment: Yes, that's better for the first part.

Comment: I thing I got it: Define $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb N$ such that $f(x)=\begin {cases}x &, x>1 \\ 1 &,x\le 0  \end{cases}$ this is onto, the reverse is to send $1$ to any non positive integer and there are $\aleph_0$ combinations for that and it's 1-1. Although I don't think $f\circ f^{-1} = id_{\mathbb N}$

Comment: Check that last thought again.

Comment: lol I just did a composition and it went back $f$ I didn't expect that... Appreciate all the help.